# How can I count the average per Key or Grouping of records from Spark Streaming DStream?

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming

I have a problem with Spark Scala which I want count the average from the dstream data,I get data from kafka to dstream like this,

> [(2,110),(2,130),(2,120),(3,200),(3,206),(3,206),(4,150),(4,160),(4,170)]

I want to count them like this,

> [(2,(110+130+120)/3),(3,(200+206+206)/3),(4,(150+160+170)/3)]

then,get the result like this,

> [(2,120),(3,204),(4,160)]

How can I do this with scala from dstream? I use spark version 1.6

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use map to convert input (x, y) -

> [(2,110),(2,130),(2,120),(3,200),(3,206),(3,206),(4,150),(4,160),(4,170)]

to (x, (y, 1)

> [(2,(110, 1)),(2,(130, 1)),(2,(120, 1)),(3,(200, 1)),(3,(206, 1)),(3,(206, 1)),(4,(150, 1)),(4,(160, 1),(4,(170, 1))]

Now, use redudceByKeyAndWindow by writing a reduce function which will add two records as -
(x, (y1, 1)) and (x,(y2, 1)) to (x, (y1+y2, 1+1)

> [(2,(360, 3)),(3,(612, 3)),(4,(480, 3))]

Run a map again to get the average now -
(x, (y1, y2)) to (x, (y1/y2))

> [(2,120),(3,204),(4,160)]

Comment: Thank you.I use like this  val agg_rdd = rdd.aggregateByKey((0,0))((acc, value) => (acc._1 + value, acc._2 + 1),(acc1, acc2) => (acc1._1 + acc2._1, acc1._2 + acc2._2))
val sum = agg_rdd.mapValues(x => (x._1/x._2))
sum.collect